# Python parse a raw email and get the text content of the body

Tags: python, email, parsing

How to get the text body of an email without the html tags.

I have tried below code to parse the mail, but I get the entire section for 
 '------=_Part_2' section as the body.

**My code**

```
import email
message = email.message_from_string(text)
print_payload(message)

def print_payload(message):
    print('******')
    if message.is_multipart():
        for payload in message.get_payload():
            print_payload(payload)
    else:
        print message.get_payload()
        for part in message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type():
                body = str(part.get_payload())
                print(body)
    print('******')
```

**Actual email body:**

Another test mail.
Thanks,
Munesh

**Raw email:**

```
Return-Path: abc@mydomain.com Date: Mon, 18 Sep 2017 23:07:16 +0000 From: abc@mydomain.com To: xyz@mydomain.com Cc: abc@mydomain.com Message-ID: <1233.5.68566565@host.corp.mydomain.com> Subject: My email subject MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: application/ms-tnef Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Originating Thread-Topic: My email subject X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: SFV:SKI;SCL:-1; X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Antispam-Report: SFV:SKI;SCL:-1; Accept-Language: en-US Content-Language: en-US

------=_Part_2_123.456 Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)"><style><!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face
        {font-family:Calibri;
        panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
        {margin:0in;
        margin-bottom:.0001pt;
        font-size:11.0pt;
        font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
        {mso-style-priority:99;
        color:blue;
        text-decoration:underline;} a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
        {mso-style-priority:99;
        color:purple;
        text-decoration:underline;} span.EmailStyle17
        {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
        font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
        color:windowtext;} .MsoChpDefault
        {mso-style-type:export-only;
        font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";} @page WordSection1
        {size:8.5in 11.0in;
        margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;} div.WordSection1
        {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" /></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:shapelayout v:ext="edit"><o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" /></o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple"><div class="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal">Another test mail.<o:p></o:p></p><p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class="MsoNormal">Thanks,<o:p></o:p></p><p class="MsoNormal">Munesh<o:p></o:p></p><p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>

------=_Part_2_123.456--
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the BeautifulSoup library, it is actually not too hard to parse the text. If you do not have the library, make sure you `pip install bs4` first. After that, it shouldn't be too hard:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def print_payload(message):
    print('******')
    if message.is_multipart():
        for payload in message.get_payload():
            print_payload(payload)
    else:
         print message.get_payload()
         for part in message.walk():
             if part.get_content_type():
                 body = str(part.get_payload())
                 soup = BeautifulSoup(body)
                 paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
                 for paragraph in paragraphs:
                     print(paragraph.text)
    print('******')
```

What BeautifulSoup does eloquently is creating a parse-tree, from which html elements can be selected. So if your e-mail has other html elements in it, you may have to also search for them to get all the data. But with this simple e-mail, finding all the html elements with the tag 'p' is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it is partially working. When I search for the tag 'p', the initial text outside the html like Part_2 and Content-Type are also getting printed. Can you guide me how to get just the mail body

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why that's happening. What if you skip the first paragraph? I.e.: `for paragraph in paragraphs[1:]`

Comment: paragraphs[1:] works. But this looks more like a hack than a proper fix. Thanks anyway. Let me know if you find a better way.

Comment: I admit it is, but HTML is notoriously difficult to parse. You could probably also use regular expressions to check for xml code and exclude anything that looks like xml, but that too would look a little messy.

Comment: I'm using text=True, to filter the unwanted data using

paragraphs_all = soup.find_all('p',text=False), 
paragraphs_extra = soup.find_all('p',text=True), 
paragraphs=set(paragraphs_all)-set(paragraphs_extra)